# Is only link in the answer allowed?

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation, answers

I have seen few one line answer with link. Is that allowed?

For example this [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/15093/5456).Why to put this type of link as answer, it is better to put it as comment. I have seen one another of same type of answer in which it was just written **See this answer.**

So what is better to put this type links as answer or as a comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is possible to flag an answer for deletion and give the reason as "Link-only answer," I would say that they are definitely discouraged, if not outright disallowed.

A comment is definitely more appropriate. The same is true for one-line answers - brevity and directness are nice, but some explanation is appropriate in almost any case. Otherwise, a comment would be a better choice.

Comment: I think this hits the nail right on the head.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I'm worried, won't making a valid answer as a comment deprive the owner his potential gainable repuatation, plus what's the harm in doing so.

Comment: @ADG I think the point is that link-only answers aren't valid. Sure, the asker could accept them, and people could upvote them, but the site rules at the very least discourage them. The harm is that early answers tend to get more votes just because they are early. If we allow low-quality answers and they manage to make it to the top of the list, it drives away people who are looking for high quality answers. Allowing them as comments is a middle-ground solution that lets people give quick responses if they think they are helpful, without risking the overall site quality.